# setup_instruments table of performance_schema in mariadb does not have any records

Tags: mariadb

I am using MariaDB server version 10.11.2. I want to enable metadata lock instrumention by following this [instruction](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/performance-schema-metadata_locks-table/). I tried both ways, enable at runtime or adjust config file. But nothing works. Then I found out that setup_instruments in performance_schema has no record. So obviously it will not work. Can anyone explain why is that. Is there any problem with this MariaDB server version? What should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may not have turned on the main Performance Schema option. To do this you need to add `performance_schema=ON` in your configuration file. It is off by default because it can cause a performance impact.

Details available here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/performance-schema-overview/

You can check this by doing `show variables like 'performance_schema';`

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day.